# WordPress jquery setup for spritespin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Seem to be hitting a wall when trying to implement some jquery for a spritespin viewer plugin. Here are the steps I have tried following:

1. adding a `wp_enqueue_script` at the top in my functions.php file as such:

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script');
    function add_my_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'spritespin.js',
            get_template_directory_uri().
            '/js/spritespin.js',
            array('jquery')
        );
    }`

2. In my page I added a div id and the following script:

`<div id='mySpriteSpin'/>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#mySpriteSpin").spritespin({
      source: [
      "/wordpress/sprite-images/rad_zoom_001.jpg",
      "/wordpress/sprite-images/rad_zoom_002.jpg",
      "/wordpress/sprite-images/rad_zoom_003.jpg",
      ],
      width   : 480,  // width in pixels of the window/frame
      height  : 327,  // height in pixels of the window/frame
    });
    $("#mySpriteSpin").spritespin({
    width : 480,
    height: 327,
    frames: frames.length,
    behavior: "drag", // "hold"
    module: "360",
    sense : -1,
    source: frames,
    animate : true,
    loop: true,
    frameWrap : true,
    frameStep : 1,
    frameTime : 60,
    enableCanvas : true
    });
    </script>`

Here are official websites with plugin info:

http://spritespin.ginie.eu/howto.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress runs jQuery in "no-conflict" mode to prevent clashing with any plugin namespaces.

Try placing your script in a `document.ready` function, like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $("#mySpriteSpin").spritespin({
     source: [
     "<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/sprite-images/rad_zoom_001.jpg",
     "<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/sprite-images/rad_zoom_002.jpg",
     "<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/sprite-images/rad_zoom_003.jpg",
   ],
     width   : 480,  // width in pixels of the window/frame
     height  : 327,  // height in pixels of the window/frame
  });

  $("#mySpriteSpin").spritespin({
   width : 480,
   height: 327,
   frames: frames.length,
   behavior: "drag", // "hold"
   module: "360",
   sense : -1,
   source: frames,
   animate : true,
   loop: true,
   frameWrap : true,
   frameStep : 1,
   frameTime : 60,
   enableCanvas : true
  });
});
</script>
```

You probably should reference the path to your images dynamically, in the event you migrate your site. Put the "sprite-images" folder inside your theme directory.

Comment: tnx - but no result.

Comment: are you sure spritespin.js is enqueued properly? try viewing the page source and seeing if it is being included.

Comment: If you're not seeing the spritespin.js reference in your page source, try adding the script reference to the header.php file of your WordPress install like so: `<script type="text/javascript"
   src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/spritespin.js"></script>`

Comment: nada.  :((
here is the url of the page if it helps to see how the jquery code is being enqueued. 
http://superchute.com/wordpress/chute-systems/construction-chutes/hoists/

Comment: It looks like your enqueue is working, so you can take the reference out of the header.php file. What I noticed is your JS for spritespin references `#mySpriteSpin` but the container you made to hold the spinner only has a class on it and no ID. Make your container like this: `<div id="mySpriteSpin" class="spritespin"></div>` so that your JS references the right container

Comment: Nothing.
Is there a plugin i could look into that simplifies jqueries?

Comment: I looked at your source code again and used Google Chrome's inspector tool and JS console(an invaluable tool for debugging). It looks like you did not include a closing right parenthesis on that spritespin JS script, around line 744 of your outputted code (not sure what line in your PHP). There is also some weird CDATA chars being inserted, so check your copy and pasting encoding.

Comment: The code included for that plugin should look like this: `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $("#mySpriteSpin").spritespin({ source: '/sprite-images/bike6x6_big.jpg', width: 480, height: 327, frames: 34, framesX: 6, sense: -1, renderer: 'image' }); });</script>`

Comment: Yup it was a closing bracket issue... it works! Many thanks :))

Comment: glad to help! select my answer as accepted, if you'd be so kind :)